# How to link a button to detail screen in React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

What is the best practice to link the whole area below to another screen?
The whole area marked with orange needs to be clickable and takes to another screen. Should I put this whole area into a view? What is the best practice here? Would appreciate a code example if possible.

[image: area marked with orange needs to be clickable]

Comment: I haven't tried any method yet, I was lost trying to decide where to start from (:

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can wrap that orange area using View component and try to use [React Native Router Flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux), the most popular and easiest way to navigate the screen/component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
...

export default class HelloWorldList extends Component {

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.componentkey}>
        <View>
          ...
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this method and report here.

Comment: This method worked perfectly for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great. Please do accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Moving from one scene (screen) to another is called navigation, there are plenty of (good and bad) navigation components packages/modules out there and most of them have an **Example** app to test and learn.

I'd recommend [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) as it's really well documented and very easy to understand also it's covered in [React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) as well.

Other packages:

- [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)
- [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)
- [native-navigation](http://airbnb.io/native-navigation/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will definitely focus on React Navigation and give a shot to the other methods.